# Django can't upload image in admin site in production

Tags: django, apache, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a model with an image field. Uploading an image for this field in the admin site is working fine locally but in production it raises a 500 error when I submit the form.

I'm using Apache

What is weird is that this error doesn't gives any extra info. The body of the response is just this

## Server Error (500)

and nothing is logged in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check media folder permissions. Try `chmod -R 777 ./media`

Comment: Also check that user `www-data` has write access to the folder.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's that. Thanks! I'll give it a try next Monday when I get access to the repo again

Comment: Great, It worked! Please aswer below so I can choose the aswer